# Scroll bottom em evento click

Tags: javascript, jquery, rolamento, jquery-animate

Preciso que a pagina desça até o rodapé quando for clicado em um `input`.

Na verdade quando o usuário clica no `input` e começa a digitar, o autocomplete do jQuery fica escondido pelo teclado do celular, então quando for clicado no `input` e o teclado mobile aparecer preciso que a pagina desça até o final, assim o `input` fica mais visível e dá pra ver as opções do autocomplete.

tentei:

```
$("input").click(function(){
  $("html, body").animate(function(){
    scrollBottom: 1000
  }, 500)
});
```

mas o `scrollBottom` não existe se não me engano...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta maneira

```
$("input").click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 500);
});
```

Fonte: [stackoverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890995/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-page-iframe)

**Veja:**

```js
$(function(){
    $("[data-toggle='bottom']").click(function(){
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
    });
});
```

```css
div{
  width:300px;
  height:1000px;
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button data-toggle="bottom">Descer</button>
  <div></div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Valeu @leonardo, eu tinha visto essa resposta em outro lugar mas não tinha entendido a lógica, na verdade eu não entendi mto ainda, `document` é a pagina inteira e `height` é o tamanho... ele pega o tamanho do documento e? hahaha mas blz funcinou do jeito que eu queria, obrigado!

Comment: @BrunoCabral Exato, ele pega o tamanho da página inteira, como isso supera a margem de scroll que a página possui, ele desce até onde pode, ou seja, até o final da pagina